# Showing stationarity thanks to integrals

Tags: stationarity, integral

Let $X_t$ be a stationary process with spectral representation $$X_t = \int_{\left[-\frac12 , \frac 12\right]}e^{2 i \pi f t}\,dZ(f).$$

Assume that $E\lvert dZ(f)\lvert^2=\lvert G(f) \rvert^2\,dF(f)$ where $F$ is a distributional function. Show that $$Y_t =\int_{\left[-\frac12 , \frac 12\right]}\frac{e^{2 i \pi f t}}{G(f)}\,dZ(f) $$
is a stationary process.

The solution I was given calculates $E(Y_tY_{t+\tau})$ and at some point says:

\begin{align*}
E(Y_tY_{t+\tau})
&=\int_{-\frac12}^\frac 12 \int_{-\frac12}^\frac 12 \frac{1}{\overline{G(f')}G(f)}\,\exp(-2\pi i(f'-f)t)\exp(-2\pi if\tau)E(\overline{dZ(f')}\,dZ(f)) \\
&=\int_{-\frac12}^\frac 12 \frac{1}{\overline{G(f)}G(f)}\,\exp(-2\pi if\tau)\,E(\overline{dZ(f)}\,dZ(f)) 
\end{align*}

I really don't understand how they got the second equality... Seems like they take $f'=f$ which for me is like saying $\iint f(x,y) \,dx\,dy=\int f(y,y)\,dy,$ which is nonsense. Is there something I am not understanding here?

Comment: The integral over $f^\prime$ introduces a Dirac delta function $\delta(f^\prime-f).$

Comment: @whuber for me $f$ is a real number

Comment: That's right: and so is $f^\prime-f,$ the argument of the delta function.

Comment: @whuber I am very sorry I do not get it. Can you elaborate ? The exp involving $f'-f$ is somehow vanishing but I dont see any reason why would it because what's inside is not necessarily an integer multiple of $2 \pi i$ right ?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function#History.